# pg_ctl: too many command-line arguments [-o initdb-options] quoting

Tags: postgresql

The [PostgreSQL Documentation about pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) describes:

> `pg_ctl init[db] [-D datadir] [-s] [-o initdb-options]`
>
> `-o initdb-options`
> `--options=initdb-options`
> Specifies options to be passed directly to the initdb command. -o can be specified multiple times, with all the given options being passed through.
>
> The initdb-options should usually be surrounded by single or double quotes to ensure that they are passed through as a group.

But at least on Windows that does not work, all combinations:

```
pg_ctl.exe init -D "C:/Test DB" -o"--pwfile=C:/XXX YYY/pg_pw.txt"
pg_ctl.exe init -D "C:/Test DB" -o"--pwfile="C:/XXX YYY/pg_pw.txt""
pg_ctl.exe init -D "C:/Test DB" -o"--pwfile='C:/XXX YYY/pg_pw.txt'"
pg_ctl.exe init -D "C:/Test DB" -o'--pwfile="C:/XXX YYY/pg_pw.txt"'
pg_ctl.exe init -D "C:/Test DB" -o"--pwfile="C:/XXX^ YYY/pg_pw.txt""
pg_ctl.exe init -D "C:/Test DB" -o"--pwfile="C:/XXX\ YYY/pg_pw.txt""
pg_ctl.exe init -D "C:/Test DB" -o"--pwfile=^"C:/XXX YYY/pg_pw.txt^""
```

fail:

```
pg_ctl: too many command-line arguments (first is "YYY/pg_pw.txt")
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\"` to escape the inner double quotes:

```
pg_ctl.exe init -D "C:/Test DB" -o"--pwfile=\"C:/XXX YYY/pg_pw.txt\""
```

Comment: Why not use `initdb` directly? e.g. `initdb -D "c:/Test DB" --pwfile=...` Btw: I highly recommend to not use a directory with a space in the name.